# Remote Glassfish JMS lookup

Tags: glassfish, jms

I want to connect to my Glassfish Server at XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX which is running on a ubuntu machine on our Server.

I want to send messages and then receive them.

My Receiver looks like this:

```
    public JMS_Topic_Receiver(){
    init();
}

public List<TextMessage> getCurrentMessages() { return _currentMessages; }

private void init(){

    env.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
    env.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "10.10.32.14"); 
    env.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "8080"); 

    try {
        ctx = new InitialContext(env); // NamingException
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void subscribeTopic(String topicName, String userCredentials) {
    try {
        TopicConnectionFactory topicConnectionFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("myTopicConnectionFactory");
        TopicConnection topicConnection = topicConnectionFactory.createTopicConnection(); 
        try {
            String temp = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
            topicConnection.setClientID(temp);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        TopicSession topicSession = topicConnection.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Topic topic = (Topic) ctx.lookup(topicName); 

        topicConnection.start();

        TopicSubscriber topicSubscriber = topicSession.createDurableSubscriber(topic, userCredentials); 
        topicSubscriber.setMessageListener(new MyMessageListener());


    }
    catch(NamingException | JMSException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And my Sender looks like this:

```
public JMS_Topic_Sender(){
    init();
}

private void init(){

    env.put("java.naming.factory.initial","com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
    env.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBHost","10.10.32.14"); 
    env.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBPort","8080");    

    try {
        ctx = new InitialContext(env);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void sendMessage(String message, String topicName)  {
    try {   
        TopicConnectionFactory topicConnectionFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("myTopicConnectionFactory");

        if (topicConnectionFactory != null) {
            TopicConnection topicConnection = topicConnectionFactory.createTopicConnection();

            TopicSession topicSession = topicConnection.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE); 
            Topic topic = (Topic) ctx.lookup(topicName); 
            topicConnection.start(); 
            TopicPublisher topicPublisher = topicSession.createPublisher(topic);
            TextMessage tm = topicSession.createTextMessage(message);
            topicPublisher.send(tm);

            topicSession.close();
            topicConnection.stop();
            topicConnection.close();    
        }
    } catch (NamingException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I got most of this code from various tutorials online.
Now when I want to do the lookup aka. -> ctx.lookup("myTopicConnectionFactory");

I get all sorts of errors thrown:

INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FEIN: 00410008: Connection abort  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 8 completed: Maybe

javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'myTopicConnectionFactory' in SerialContext  ........

My question here is, how do I do the lookup correctly? 
My guess is that my Propertys (env) are incorrect and I need to change thouse, but I dont know to what?

Also, it works if i run my Glassfish localy on my own Computers localhost.
When im using localhost as adress and 8080 as port.